# How to Split a string into 2 lists by using a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am an intern and I am developing a solution in C # which allows me to retrieve a string of characters in a cell of an excel file. Once this string has been retrieved, the elements of this string must be separated into 2 other lists (sample and reference) using a regex. It means that if an element of this string corresponds to the regex, it must be sent in the "sample" list and if it does not correspond, it must be sent in the "reference list" ".

For several days, I have been trying to fix this problem but I cannot do it I first tried the regex split method but it did not work as it should, when I launch the console there is no element that is displayed.
And then I went on the regex match method with a condition inside but it doesn't work the way I want.

"CellValue1" corresponds to string of characters retrieved from the excel cell.

Examples of string of characters :

Example 1: "QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ; "

Example2 : " ; C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2 ; Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ; "

Can you help me find a solution to my problem?

```
List<string> sample = new List<string>();
                    List<string> reference = new List<string>();
                    string pattern = @"^C-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-S-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$";
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    Regex delim = new Regex(@"\s*,\s*");
                   
                     foreach (string term in delim.Split(cellValue1.Trim()))
                    {
                        
                        if (term =="")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (rgx.IsMatch(term))
                        {
                            sample.Add(term);
                            sample.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reference.Add(term);
                            reference.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

                        }
```

I did this, is it correct ?

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: ""CellValue1" corresponds to string of characters retrieved from the excel cell." welcome to StackOverflow. sorry but this information does not help us very much to be able to help you. you need to provide a examplary string! or preferably several of them. for each category

Comment: I AM soory, no problem i'll provide you several example of string :                             
Example 1: "QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ; "                           Example2 : "  ; C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2 ; Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ; 
 "

Comment: Thank you that is better, but you can (and should) use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66312193/edit) button below your post, to add this information. It does not belong into the comment section. and please describe exatly which string you expect to go into wich list

Comment: i am sorry, i'm new in stackoverflow that's why i don't know how to use it properly, thank you for the information, i'll do it from now

Comment: You should use string methods when possible instead of Regex.  You have a simple CSV data seperated by a semicolon.  So I would use input.split(new char[] {';'}).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

By your description what you have to do is first split your string, and then test each element individually.

```cs
    string pattern = @"^C-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-S-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    Regex delim = new Regex( @"\s*,\s*");
    foreach(string term in delim.Split(cellValue.Trim()))
    {
      if(rgx.IsMatch(term)){
        sample.Add(term);
      }else{
        reference.Add(term);
      }
    }
```

https://repl.it/@AlexandreFelip1/C#

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question, Can it work for all types of strings ? Because the strings can vary, it's not always the same.

Comment: I am only answering your question, I imagine you know how to create variables, you have to combine my answer with your code by yourself. I just wanted to give you a working answer. If that is confusing for you I will remove that part.

Comment: No don't remove it, it will help me a lot. thank you

Comment: Sorry to disturb again but do you know how to solve the compilation error : "  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' " ?

Comment: Check the type you used in the declaration of the variable you are using.

Comment: it is string type of the variable term in the foreach

Comment: and the other side of the assignment?

Comment: foreach(string term in delim.Split(cellValue1.Trim()))                                                                Cellvalue1 is a string from the excel . The error is on the variable "term "in "sample.add(term)" which is in the "if(rgx.Ismatch(term))".                                                It is also the same case for the else

Comment: I bet you are declaring `sample` as `List<Match>`

Comment: I edited my post can you please look at it can say it it correct even if when i'm building the code note is displayed for the sample list ?

Comment: That seems to be good, only one detail `if(term == "") break` if you want to accept lists with empty elements, I was using that to test on the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand clearly what you said about 'if(term == "") break'. Can you explain me again please ?

Comment: Well, this means that if the list have an empty item it will ignore the rest of the list. e.g. "1,2,,3,4" will add only the elements 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh great thank you for the explanation. and I have a last question, How can I display the sample list ? because in my example i have 2 element of the list which should coorespond to the regex but when I run the code, there are all the item of the list which are displayed

Comment: Check the updated answer, and you really should go to the documentations, and search more carefully, the questions you asked on the comments are probably already covered by other questions. Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and your answers